# 'Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage' 2K8 R2 SP1 https

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, https

Ever since updating a box to SP1, https sites can no longer be access with simple an 'Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage'. I have turned off the 'Show friendly HTTP error messages'.

There is nothing in the event viewer and I cannot seem to get any logs anywhere else.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this? (Or how I can get any more information on it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like your https binding isn't working.  Can you verify that the binding is still set in IIS, and that the certificate is still set for the binding?

After that, make sure that the process is actually listening on port 443; `netstat -an` should have this near the top of the output:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:443            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

Comment: It was a problem with the https binding. There was no certificate set. Once I set one, everything started working properly.

Answer (score 2):

Always start from the bottom and work your way up You might want to check that you can still resolve the server and connect to it with telnet via HTTP/HTTPS.

```
nslookup www.servername.tld
ping www.servername.tld
telnet www.servername.tld 80
telnet www.servername.tld 443
```

After that, do as Shane said in the other answer and check your certificates and bindings.

Answer (score 2):

There was a change with extensionless URLs with SP1 that breaks some sites.  That may be what you're running into.  It can affect your default doc.  Here's a [hotfix that fixes that](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=41bdce1f-3cb3-44bb-9b33-23a1b8c99ac3&displaylang=en).